# Reload an image from a remote server every x seconds without reloading whole page

Tags: javascript, html, image, reload

I need to refresh the image in one *img* tag. My problem is that the *src* of the image is an URL to a remote server which I can't control. So if I try using something like:

**Script:**

```
setTimeout(function(){
       document.getElementById("myImage").src = "someIpAddress:8080/some/path/status?someId=123456" + "&rand=" + Math.random()
    },5000);
```

**HTML:**

```
 <div>
    <img src="someIpAddress:8080/some/path/status?someId=123456" id="myImage" >
 </div>
```

the server gives me 500 and nothing is shown. If I try to reload the page it works, but there is a short interval where there is the blank page and I would like to avoid this or at least reduce this interval as much as possible. I already tried even using Image and canvas, but I got no results. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try removing `rand` query-string parameter ? Does server handles it properly ? If it works first time, it should work every time as long as server serves you..

Comment: 500 error is server side issue, fix it first

Comment: You need to narrow down what is causing that 500 error. Inspect your logs for the different requests and see what's happening on the server.

Comment: have you tried to add 0 before the Id ? someId=0123456, someId=00123456...

Comment: As others said, a 500 error indicates a crash on the server somehow...it's not a problem in your JavaScript. You need to check logs or debug the server code to find out what the error was.

Comment: as I said I have no control on the server response, and the static url I give him it works. It does not work if i add some random parameter at the end of the request, and if i keep the same url of the first request, the image simply does not refresh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using `#`

```
..some/path/status?someId=123456#RandomStuff
```